# I want to covert a custom Django view to an Django-Rest_framework Endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django Rest framework, I would like to convert my Payment view in Django which uses an external endpoint(flutterwave endpoint) to an endpoint. I have gone through the official Django Rest Framework documentation, but most of the example there uses models inclusive to make list, detail, delete and update endpoint.
I would be glad if I can get a solution to my problem.

**P.S: I have removed my secret key**

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

# Create your views here.

# PAYSTACK VERIFICATION
def verify_paystack_payment(request):

    url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/262762380"

    payload = {
        "email": "myemail@yahoo.com",
        "amount": "10000",
        "currency": "NGN",
        "reference": "262762380",
        "metadata": {
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "display_name": "Mobile Number",
                    "variable_name": "mobile_number",
                    "value": "+2348012345678"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    files = {}
    # The Bearer can either be an account or sub-account, but the default is account

    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {{SECRET_KEY}}',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)

    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))

    return render(request, "transaction/pay.html")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go through the https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ thoroughly, you could get a solution there.
Have a great day.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)